# Dax code: find sum of values filtered by month

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax, filtered-statistics

I have seen some posts that address this concept online, but I have been unable to adapt them to my needs.

Scenario:
 I have a table with three columns.
    Column A- [Month] (formatted mm/dd/yyyy)
    Column B- [salesperson]
    Column C- [Assets]

I am trying to determine a formula which will return the total assets for all salespeople for each month in a fourth column.

Why am I doing this? I am building a report which will generate a graph from this data. In reality there will be additional columns which will contain values for some variables. I will be using the slicer function in conjunction with these variables to create an interactive functionality within the graph. Hard coded references won't work for me, as this will be a recurring report, and the dataset will be refreshed with current data regularly.

Thank you for any help you can offer. I'm still fairly new to all this (<1yr) so interpreting general formulas I've found elsewhere has been very problematic.

Cheers!

Comment: which column has unique values month or salesperson ? can you show one example with sample data ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculation like this (syntax dependent on data model)

```
AllSalespersons:=CALCULATE(SUM[Assets], ALL[Salesperson])
```

Using the CALCULATE function here is important because it will remove the row syntax for Salesperson (created in the pivottable) and give you the sum of 'ALL' salespersons for each month.

Again, you'll have to play with the syntax to fit your data model, but based on your quetsion, I think this should give you what you are looking for.